# During a night, each chameleon changes its colour to one of the other four colours with equal probability.

Tags: probability, contest-math

Five chameleons of all different colours meet one evening. During the night, each chameleon changes its colour to one of the other four colours with equal probability. Find the probability that the next day the five chameleons have all different colours again.

My attempt: We can split the five chameleons into two groups, one has two chameleons and another has three, say $A_1$ and $A_2$. In $A_1$, the probability is $\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4}$. In $A_2$, the probability is $\frac{2}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4}$. So the total probability is $\frac{1}{4^2} \times \frac{2}{4^3} \times 10=\frac{20}{4^5}$. But the answer given is $\frac{44}{4^5}$. May I know what is my mistake?

Comment: If there are only 4 different colors how come 5 chameleons have all different colors?

Comment: each charmaleon has one color and there are other 4 possibilities(given the charmeleon)

Comment: How did you come up with $\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: @DavidZ: In $A_2$, say we have $1,2,3$, we simply pick one, say $3$. $3$ has two choices $(1,2)$, so $\frac{2}{4}$. Say it changes to $2$, then $2$ must change to $1$, otherwise there won't be three different numbers, so is $\frac{1}{4}$. Same reasoning to obtain the last $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @Idonknow but chameleon 3 could also change to one of the colors from $A_1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of permutations without fixed points in $S_5$ is given by:
$$ 5!\left(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{5!}\right)=\color{red}{44}\tag{1} $$
by the inclusion-exclusion principle, hence the wanted probability is:
$$ \frac{44}{4^5} = \color{red}{\frac{11}{256}}\approx 4,3\%.\tag{2}$$

Comment: May I know what is the general formula for the number of permutation without fixed points in $S_n$?

Comment: @Idonknow: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment given by David Z, I got the answer.

There can only be two possibilities, first is three cameleons and two cameleons, and second is five cameleons. The first case is already calculated in the question. Here I will only focus on second case.

Assume that the five chameleons are named $1,2,3,4,5$. Suppose we pick one chameleon randomly, say $1$, and it can change to any number (except $1$). So the probability is $\frac{4}{4}$. Say it changes to $2$. Then $2$ cannot change to $1$, otherwise we will have first case. So the probability that $2$ changes to other number is $\frac{3}{4}$. $3$ cannot change to either $1$ or $2$, otherwise we will have the first case. Performing the reasoning, we obtain 
$$\frac{4}{4} \times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{24}{4^5}$$

Summing the two probabilities,we obtain 
$$\frac{44}{4^5}$$